# Does the Nix package manager have a data format spec allowing alternative implementations, similarly to Git?

Tags: nixos

Does the Nix package manager have a data format spec allowing alternative implementations ?

For example : Can tools be written for Nix that does not reuse any of Nix's code, but only looks at config files, package stores, etc ? Such tools could be utilities like "add package, remove package, list package, show versions of package, etc..."

The rest is a justification for the question.

I find that one of the strengths of Git is that it's specified at the file format level. This has many advantages, like interoperability, but more importantly, would allow Git to survive even if the implementation quality would degrade over time.

I find the concept of Nix brilliant. I think functional package managers are the next step in evolution. However I'm not so satisfied by the implementation, obscure error message, etc. The fact that it's implemented in C++ certainly adds extra challenges that are a huge net cost to the project. I understand the need to be "lightweight" and without dependencies. It seems that golang would have had all the benefits with much less costs.

If Nix is specified at the file format level, then the language of the initial implementation matters much less, if not, well Nix can only ever be as good as it's single implementation.

Comment: The "nix" language is relatively well specified, so one could re-implement it, but the performance would be difficult to replicate with a different approach (e.g. through some other functional language) and dependencies would likely blow a lot.